# C++ Cyclic Dependency Design

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

Been using the solutions for a while... first question asked. (Not sure if this is the proper venue). I am stuck with a design problem.

I have 3 classes, User, Strategy, & Communicator.

I would like User to have a pointer to Communicator, and call functions when necessary.

I would like User to have a list of class Strategy, and call functions of Strategy when necessary.

I would like Communicator to have a list of class Strategy, and a pointer to User, and call functions on those when necessary.

If it helps, Communicator is merely a wrapper around a socket connection which listens to messages from the client and sends them to User or Strategy, whichever is appropriate. It also contains a function `Send(string message)` which sends messages from User & Strategy to the client.

The problem is that I cannot compile, since the header files end up including each other. 
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the Q? You need ideas on what?

Comment: edited the question, I am basically looking to avoid the header files including each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forward declarations are your friends.

Strategy.h:

```
class User;
class Communicator;

class Strategy {
    /* Definition of Strategy, restricted use of User and Communicator */
};
```

Strategy.cpp:

```
#include "Strategy.h"
#include "User.h"
#include "Communicator.h"

/* Full use of all three classes */
```

Comment: If I forward declare the class, I cannot use it's functions, right?

Comment: Not in the header.  But you can `#include` the header in the source file and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Joshua: You can, if you delay the definition of the functions in Strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[Forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)** to avoid cyclic inclusion of headers.

Note that Forward Declaration has its own limitations on how the Incomplete type can be used further on.
With Incomplete type you can:

- Declare a member to be a pointer to the incomplete type.
- Declare functions or methods which accepts/return incomplete types.
- Define functions or methods which accepts/return pointers to the incomplete type (but without using its members).

With Incomplete type you cannot:

- Use it to declare a member.
- Define functions or methods using this type.

Comment: If I forward declare the class, I cannot use it's functions, right?

Comment: OK, I understand. I did not realize I could just include the header file in the source file as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want to hear but talking about c++ the circular dependency problem is solved by using boost::enable_shared_from_this and boost::shared_ptr.

HTH